# Display largest available creative in Google DFP responsive ads

Tags: responsive-design, google-dfp

We're using [DFP responsive ads](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en) but cannot figure out how to get it to show the largest size available that will fit. For example, if both leaderboard (728x90) and a super leaderboard (900x90) creatives exist, it should show the super leaderboard when the browser is wider than 900px (desktop), from 900px to 738px wide (tablet) it should show the leaderboard.

Existing mapping (I've left out the rest of the ad code for clarity):

```
var leaderboardMapping = [
      [[900, 300], [[900,90],[728,90]]],
      [[738, 300], [728,90]]
];
```

This always shows the leaderboard at tablet size, but the problem is, this will alternate between the leaderboard and super leaderboard at desktop size.

I've tried this to specify preference, but the second value of the same size seems to be ignored.

```
var leaderboardMapping = [
      [[900, 300], [900,90]],
      [[900, 300], [728,90]],
      [[738, 300], [728,90]]
];
```

The only solution we have at the moment is to use DFPs device targeting for tablet, but that doesn't fit well with use of responsive design and will miss out on serving ads to desktop users with their browser < 900px wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up with a solution that is not ideal but works for us so I thought it's worth sharing.

We still use the initial mapping

```
var leaderboardMapping = [
  [[900, 300], [[900,90],[728,90]]],
  [[738, 300], [728,90]]
];
```

In the line item we then use [weighted creative rotations](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177245?hl=en)

Then set the larger creative (900x300) with the highest weight possible (100) and set the smaller creative (728x90) with the lowest weight possible (0.001).

If my maths are correct the smaller size will now only show 1 / 100,000 impressions. Not perfect but negligible for our circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming along later and finding this post. This can now be done using Creative Targetting. You can assign targetting for the different ad sizes you provide, so an MPU (300x250) can be served on mobile only, while a Billboard can be served on Desktop and tablet. All within the same line item.